# Database connection from c# using PowerBuilder 12.5 with specific port

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection, port, powerbuilder

Does anybody know how to connect to a SQL Server database using PowerBuilder 12.5 with a specific SQL Server port?

Connection by native `SqlConnection` (of course) works, but I need to create a database connection by Sybase/Powerbuilder.

There are in .NET C# projects used just four dll from Sybase:

```
Sybase.DataWindow.Common
Sybase.DataWindow.Core
Sybase.DataWindow.Shared
Sybase.DataWindow.WPF
```

Used code (.net framework 4.0):

```
var dwSQLCA = new Sybase.DataWindow.Shared.DWTransaction();
dwSQLCA.Dbms = "ADO.Net";
var parms = new List<string>();
//parms.Add("DecimalSeparator='.'");
//parms.Add("DisableBind=1");

parms.Add($"Namespace='System.Data.SqlClient'");
parms.Add($"DataSource='{srvNameWithPort}'");
parms.Add($"Database='{dbName}'");
parms.Add($"TimeOut=15");
parms.Add("CommandTimeOut=3600");
if (pf.WinAuth)
{
    parms.Add("TrustedConnection=1");
}
else
{
    dwSQLCA.UserId = dbi.UserLogin;
    dwSQLCA.Password = dbi.Pwd;
}
//dwSQLCA.AutoCommit = true;
dwSQLCA.DBParm = string.Join(",", parms);
dwSQLCA.Connect();
```

The variable `srvNameWithPort` contains server with port in standard format `server,port_number`.

This ends with this exception:

> Index #0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) Number: 5 State: 0

I cannot find any way to set a specific SQL Server port if I use Sybase/Powerbuilder 12.5 library.

Neither `server,3345` nor `server:3345` work.

The code above works if the server port is not specified.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/use-server-name-parameter-connection-string . According to https://docs.appeon.com/pb2019/connection_reference/ch01s01.html#DataSource_conref, "setting ServerName is the equivalent to setting DataSource". See also: https://docs.appeon.com/pb2019r2/connecting_to_your_database/ch05s03.html, . Try `DataSource=tcp:serverName, 3345`

Comment: You may also want test using "ServerName" instead of "DataSource"

Comment: Thanks for answers, usage of "ServerName" ends with exception "Data source is not provided."

Usage of "DataSource=tcp:serverName, 3345" does not help. I have tested connectivity to the sql server in SSMS - sql server works with native connection, but not through Sybase/Powerbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I found that the problem is in Powerbuilder version 12.5. In Powerbuilder 2019, the above code works correctly.